# Trying to get property 'mapname' of non-object

Tags: php, json

I really don't see why it's not working, any help?

PHP:

```php
<?php

$json = file_get_contents("db/main.json");
$decoded = json_decode($json);

foreach ($decoded as $game){
    echo $game->mapname;
}

?>
```

JSON:

```json
{
  "1": [
    {
      "servname": "Test place",
      "mapname": "Crossroads",
      "ip": "1.1.1.1",
      "port": "1337",
      "plimit": "12"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have seen other examples before here on stackoverflow and they match my code, I really don't understand why it is not working, if the json is parsed, and if a return it in encoded json it shows the proper array.

Error: `Notice: Trying to get property 'mapname' of non-object`

Answer (score 1):

Because of the slightly strange JSON structure you have `"1"` is a property of an object and an array of objects, so

```
$json = '{
    "1": [
      {
        "servname": "Test place",
        "mapname": "Crossroads",
        "ip": "1.1.1.1",
        "port": "1337",
        "plimit": "12"
      }
    ]
  } 
';
$decoded = json_decode($json);
if (json_last_error() != 0) { echo json_last_error_msg();}

foreach ($decoded as $game){
    echo $game[0]->mapname;
}
```

OR you could do

```
foreach ($decoded as $game){
    foreach ($game as $g) {
        echo $g->mapname;
    }
}
```

> Beware, as PHP does not allow variables starting with a numeric, you are on dangerous ground having anything call "1"